# Arduino How to POST a request to a HTTPS with ArduinoHttpClient

Tags: https, arduino-uno

I'm pretty new on Arduino. I'm using ArduinoHttpClient and need to POST a request in secure way (https://).
I'm not able to define the https:// on the serverName passed to HttpClient(ethernetClient, serverName, webServerPort).
When I use serverName = url (ssl9083.websiteseguro.com or 179.188.19.74) with port 443 the board hangs and after sometime returns -3 on httpClient.responseStatusCode().

I'm using Arduino Uno R3 with Ethernet Shield W5100.

I'd appreciate any help. Below the code.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>

//UDP Variables
#define UDP_PACKET_SIZE 80 //UDP size
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress localIp(192, 168, 1, 9);
unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on
char packetBuffer[UDP_PACKET_SIZE];  // buffer to hold incoming packet,
EthernetUDP Udp; // An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP

//Http Variables
// Environment = P, H, D
char ENV[1] = {'H'};
const char* devServerName = "192.168.1.105";
const char* homServerName = "179.188.19.74";
//const char* homServerName = "https://ssl9083.websiteseguro.com/cfbinformatica"; Port 80 - NOK Frooze
//const char* homServerName = "https://ssl9083.websiteseguro.com"; Port 80 - NOK Frooze
//const char* homServerName = "ssl9083.websiteseguro.com/cfbinformatica"; Port 80 - NOK Frooze
//const char* homServerName = "ssl9083.websiteseguro.com"; Port 80 - OK conectou e retornou 404
//const char* homServerName = "179.188.19.74"; Port 80 OK conectou e retornou 404 - Port 443 retornou -3
const char* prdServerName = "ssl9083.websiteseguro.com/cfbinformatica";
String measurementServiceInsertMeasurement = "/MeasurementService.svc/InsertMeasurement";
String postInsertMeasurement = "/MeasurementService.svc/InsertMeasurement";
String serverName;
int webServerPort;
EthernetClient ethernetClient;
String authUserUid;
String userValidationUidCredentials;

void setup() {
  setupSerial();
  setupEthernetUDP();
  setupHttp();
}

void setupSerial() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
}

void setupEthernetUDP() {
  // start the Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, localIp);
  Serial.print("IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Etn shield notFnd");
    while (1);
  }
  
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Cable notConn");
    while (1);
  }

  // start UDP
  Udp.begin(localPort);
  Serial.println("UDP init OK");
  delay(5000);
}

void setupHttp() {
  // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
    
    switch(ENV[0]) {
    case 'P' :
      serverName = prdServerName;
      webServerPort = 443;
      postInsertMeasurement = "/housemeterprd" + measurementServiceInsertMeasurement;
      break;
    case 'H' :
      serverName = homServerName;
      webServerPort = 443;
      postInsertMeasurement = "/cfbinformatica/housemeterhom" + measurementServiceInsertMeasurement;
      break;
    default :
      serverName = devServerName;
      webServerPort = 80;
      postInsertMeasurement = "/housemeterdev" + measurementServiceInsertMeasurement;
  }
  authUserUid = "Mg==";
  userValidationUidCredentials = "PlUfGKwdXKmcF7HEoEPFu5QqGA3w52ukaUsIp5gOOlOXX928fermbxvGNsfbVr4Q";
  Serial.println("HTTP init OK");
}

void loop() {
  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3) {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    readPackage();
    processPackage();
  }
  delay(10);
}

void readPackage() {
  // read the packet into packetBufffer
  Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_PACKET_SIZE);
  Serial.println("Contents:");
  Serial.println(packetBuffer);
}

void processPackage() {
  switch(packetBuffer[0]) {
    case 'A' :
      handleAckMsg();
      break;
    case 'E' :
      handleErrorMsg();
      break;
    default :
      handleDataMsg();
  }
}

void handleAckMsg() {
  
}

void handleErrorMsg() {
  
}

void handleDataMsg() {
  String meterMAC;
  meterMAC = convertToString(packetBuffer+35, 12);
  String measurementValue;
  measurementValue = convertToString(packetBuffer+20, 15);
  String postData = "{\"meterMAC\":\"" + meterMAC + "\",\"measurementValue\":" + measurementValue +"}";
  sendHttpPostDataMsg(&postData);
  replyBack();
}

void sendHttpPostDataMsg(String *postData) {
  Serial.print(serverName); 
  Serial.println(" Server ");
  Serial.print(webServerPort); 
  Serial.println(" port ");
  Serial.print(postInsertMeasurement); 
  Serial.println(" Url");
  String data = *postData;
  Serial.print(data); 
  Serial.println(" data ");
  Serial.print(data.length()); 
  Serial.println(" data length ");

  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(ethernetClient, serverName, webServerPort);
    
  httpClient.beginRequest();
  httpClient.post(postInsertMeasurement);
  
  httpClient.sendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
  httpClient.sendHeader("Content-Length", data.length()); 
  httpClient.sendHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  httpClient.sendHeader("AuthUserUid", authUserUid);
  httpClient.sendHeader("AuthUserValidationUid", userValidationUidCredentials);
  httpClient.sendHeader("DeviceLanguage", "English");
  httpClient.sendHeader("AuthUserProfile", "user");

  httpClient.beginBody();
  httpClient.print(data);
  
  httpClient.endRequest();
  int statusCode = httpClient.responseStatusCode();
  String response = httpClient.responseBody();
  
  httpClient.flush();
  httpClient.stop();
  
  Serial.print(statusCode); 
  Serial.println(" Http ret code");
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);      
}

void replyBack() {
  // send a reply to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
  Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
  Udp.write(packetBuffer);
  Udp.endPacket();
}

String convertToString(char* arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    String s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s = s + arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

here the results of the http call:

21:30:49.179 -> IP: 192.168.1.9

21:30:49.179 -> UDP init OK

21:30:54.226 -> HTTP init OK

21:31:05.891 -> Received packet of size 47

21:31:05.891 -> From 192.168.1.32, port 58412

21:31:05.937 -> Contents:

21:31:05.937 -> 000000000000000010330000000017.9090DEADBEEFFEED

21:31:05.985 -> 179.188.19.74 Server

21:31:06.031 -> 443 port

21:31:06.031 -> /cfbinformatica/housemeterhom/MeasurementService.svc/InsertMeasurement Url

21:31:06.125 -> {"meterMAC":"DEADBEEFFEED","measurementValue":0000000017.9090} data

21:31:06.172 -> 62 data length

21:32:07.214 -> -3 Http ret code

21:32:07.214 -> Response:

Comment: it is not possible. Uno can't make in time the calculations required to encrypt the communication

Comment: Hi Juraj, thank you for the information. Do you know if there is any Arduino shield that supports https? Thank you.

Comment: all WiFi networking has it